# Subquery as a column : Nested Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 'Student' and 'Team'. i want to display count of student according to Team Name, Team_id from team is primary key.

i tried like this

```
(SELECT(SELECT team,count(*) as team 
            FROM student GROUP BY team) AS total,
     (SELECT team_name 
          from team WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team 
              FROM student GROUP BY team)) as team)
```

i want output as

```
Team Name      Total Student
-----------------------------
Team 1           25
Team 2           10
```

Table ' Student'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rid` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `height` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `age_group` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `weight_group` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `belt` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `black_belt` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ikata` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ikumite` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `team_kata` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `special_entry` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `challange` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `weapon` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 'Team'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `team_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `coach_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `coach_number` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `coach_email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `gold` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Could you post your table structure?

Comment: Subqueries in SELECT clauses may not return multiple results.

Comment: How are these tables related? In other words, how do you associate a Student with a Team?

Comment: columns 'Team' in student table is 'Team_id' in Team table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this

```
 select a.team_name, count(*) 
 from  team as a
 inner join student as b on a.id = b.team
 group by a.team_name
```

(use your proper column for join)

Comment: @TinTran   yes .. was typing ... thanks  .. i have added  the group by

Comment: Giving syntax error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) @scaisEdge

Comment: @PrincePrakash   show me the entire messege  ... near ....... this is part i need   ... eventually show me the exact query you are using  ..

Comment: ' select a.team_name, b.count(*) from  team as a inner join student as b on a.team_id = b.team group by a.team_name    ' this is the query i am using @scaisEdge